# RadComboBox Cell text in RadGridGriew

Tags: telerik-test-studio

Am Recording web Application. That is silver light application.I have a RadGridView with a column that is RadComboBox:

when am selecting item from RadComboBox item is not selecting while running.that step is failing.

Find the below code :

```
SilverlightApp app = ActiveBrowser.SilverlightApps()[0];
RadGridView grid = app.Find.ByAutomationId<RadGridView>("RadGridViewName");
Assert.IsNotNull(grid);
GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[2];
row.User.Click(MouseClickType.LeftDoubleClick);

Telerik.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.RadComboBox   
cb=row.Find.ByType<Telerik.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.RadComboBox>();

cb.SelectItem("Football", true);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

But am getting out of index error. Let me know where am doing mistake....

Comment: Can you show details of your error?

Comment: Element is not Found Error is displaying.

Comment: Full details? It's best to copy and paste the full error information into your question.

Comment: Am Attaching full error.